# Как удалить элементы из массива, используя элементы из другого массива?

Tags: javascript, typescript

У меня есть два массива

```
let unnecessaryNames: Array<string> = ["Alex", "Dmitry", "Rustam"];
let names: Array<number, string> = [1, "Maxim", 2, "Oleg", 3, "Alex", 4, "Dmitry", 5, "Rustam", 6, "Roman"];
```

мне нужно удалить из массива `names` все элементы, совпадающие с элементами массива  `unnecessaryNames`, чтобы на выходе в массиве `names` остались `[1, "Maxim", 2, "Oleg", 6, "Roman"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
let unnecessaryNames = ["Alex", "Dmitry", "Rustam"];
let names = [1, "Maxim", 2, "Oleg", 3, "Alex", 4, "Dmitry", 5, "Rustam", 6, "Roman"];

for (let i = 1; i < names.length; i += 2) {
  if (unnecessaryNames.includes(names[i])) {
    names.splice(i-1, 2);
    i -= 2;
  }
}

console.log(names);
```